# adding a response header to 302 response using perl

Tags: perl, http, http-headers, http-status-code-302

i am trying to write a perl page that returns an http 302 response to a different location and adds a custom header to that response.
so my desired http response should be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved
Date: Sun, 15 Apr 2012 10:59:02 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.google.com
Content-Length: 396
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
CUSTOM_HEADER: CUSTOM_VALUE
```

i tried using CGI:

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use APR::Request::Apache2;
my $r = shift;
$r->content_type('text/html; charset=utf-8');
$r->headers_out()->add("CUSTOM_HEADER", "CUSTOM_VALUE");
$r->headers_out()->add("Location", "http://www.google.com");
$r->status(302);
```

and i do get 302 response to google but no CUSTOM_HEADER. once i change the status to 200 by  `$r->status(200);` i do get the CUSTOM_HEADER.
so whats up with this behavior ? how can i add my header to the 302 response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$r->err_headers_out->set` or `$r->err_headers_out->add`

```
my $r = shift;

$r->content_type('text/html; charset=utf-8');
$r->err_headers_out->set(Location => "http://www.google.com");
$r->status(302);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. by the way, why does 302 considered as an error response ?

Comment: @Oded - Good question. I got your point :) Status codes 1xx are Informational, 2xx Success, 3xx Redirection, 4xx Client Error and 5xx Server Error. So 302 is not Success, not Error. So what it is? In this case for this module and functionality it is error. Don't ask why :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`err_headers_out()`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_err_headers_out_). These will be printed even on errors and redirects.